# Why do we must use SQLAlchemy with PostgreSQL in a Flask app development?

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, sqlalchemy

I am new to Flask development. But I noticed that people are using SQLAlchemy even when they are using PostgreSQL as their database. I am wondering why is it required. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to use SQLAlchemy with Flask and Postgresql. Under the hood, SQLAlchemy makes use of the Psycopg database adapter (http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/) and you can use that directly in a Flask application if you wish.

The main reasons most people probably choose to use SQLAlchemy are:

1. The ORM (object-relational-mapper http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/tutorial.html) - this makes it really easy to map your python classes directly to database tables and makes it possible to manipulate the database via your python objects
2. Session awareness (http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/patterns/sqlalchemy/) - SQLAlchemy can integrated in Flask in such a way as to provide a database transaction lifespan that matches the lifespan of an incoming web request - essentially you get a unique database connection for each request, providing a nice level of isolation

Comment: I'd add independence from any particular database to the list. Used properly, switching from Postgres to any other database is as simple as changing the configuration.

Comment: Thanks for the elaborate answer. I was going through this project example [link](https://realpython.com/blog/python/flask-by-example-part-2-postgres-sqlalchemy-and-alembic/) for my own project, but I couldn't understand the purpose of using SQLAlchemy here. Same for another project [link](http://blog.sahildiwan.com/posts/flask-and-postgresql-app-deployed-on-heroku/). Both are using SQLAlchemy like there's a fundamental need for it. So are they using it for the ORM part or the Session awareness part? @user783836

Comment: In both cases they are making use of the ORM e.g. `class Result(db.Model):` is defining . a `Result` class that extends the SQLAlchemy `Model` class.  In the first case they are making use of a db migration tool which, I assuming, ties into SQLAlchemy. In the second they are additionally using `SQLAlchemy` to create their db from their data model (another feature). What you're going to find is that SQLAlchemy has been around long enough that other cool tools you'll want to use assume you are using it by default.